# Filtrations and the Betti cycle map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety.

Calling $f : X_{\rm an}\to X_{\rm Zar}$ the "change-of-topology" morphism of sites induced by sending a Zariski open $U$ of $X$ to its analytification, the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence reads:

$$\mathbb{H}^p(X_{\rm Zar}, R^qf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$$

It induces a filtration on the target: define

$$F^wH^r(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n)) := \text{Im}(\mathbb{H}^r(X_{\rm Zar},\tau_{\ge w}Rf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\to H^r(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))).$$

> **The question is:** do we have
>   $$\text{gr}^n(H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n)), F^{\bullet}) = \text{Hdg}^n(X)$$
>   at least after tensoring with $\mathbf{Q}$?

*I'd appreciate a lot if someone could point me to an answer.*

**The same question, as previously formulated.**

Call $\mathcal{H}^*(\mathbf{Z}(n))$ the **Zariski** sheafification of Betti cohomology with $\mathbf{Z}(n)$ coefficients (ie. the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto H^*(U^{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$, $U$ ranging over all Zariski opens in the algebraic variety $X$.)

Consider the spectral sequence $\mathbb{H}^p(X_{\rm Zar},\mathcal{H}^q(\mathbf{Z}(n)))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n)).$

> **Question.** Is the image of the edge map $$\mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar},\mathcal{H}^n(\mathbf{Z}(n)))\to H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$$
>   the group of Hodge cycles $\text{Hdg}^n(X)$? Is it after tensoring with $\mathbf{Q}$?

**Motivation for the question.**

One can prove that $$\mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n)_{\mathcal{D}}) \simeq \text{CH}^n(X),$$

for $\mathbf{Z}(n)_{\mathcal{D}}$ the Deligne complex on $X_{\rm an}$.

The map of complexes on $X_{\rm an}$:

$$\mathbf{Z}(n)_{\mathcal{D}}\to\mathbf{Z}(n)$$

induces a map

$$R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n)_{\mathcal{D}}\to R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n)$$
and therefore:

$$\text{CH}^n(X)\simeq \mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar},R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n)_{\mathcal{D}})\to \mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))$$

which composed with the edge map in the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence $\mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\to H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$ gives the two maps:

$$(*)\ \ \ \text{CH}^n(X)\to \mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\to H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$$
which agrees with the Betti cycle map.

In other words, the Betti cycle map factors through $\mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))$. The Hodge Conjecture predicts that after tensoring with $\mathbf{Q}$, the image of the composition, and hence of the map

$$\mathbb{H}^n(X_{\rm Zar}, R^nf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\otimes\mathbf{Q}\to H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))\otimes\mathbf{Q}$$

really is $\text{Hdg}^n(X)\otimes\mathbf{Q}$. In other words, under the Hodge Conjecture we **do** know:

$$\text{gr}^n(H^{2n}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n)), F^{\bullet})\otimes\mathbf{Q} = \text{Hdg}^n(X)\otimes\mathbf{Q}.$$

> My question is: is rational surjectivity of the **second map** alone in $(*)$ onto Hodge classes, provable unconditionally?

Comment: Hmm -- isn't $\mathcal{H}^*(\mathbb{Z}(n))=0$ for $*\not=0$ (since complex varieties are locally contractible)?  Or maybe I don't understand what you mean by $\mathcal{H}^*(\mathbb{Z}(n))$...

Comment: @DanielLitt You're correct. I meant *Zariski* sheafification.

Comment: In other words, given $f : X_{\rm an}\to X_{\rm Zar}$ the morphism of sites induced by $U\mapsto U^{\rm an}$, ie. coarsening the topology, your spectral sequence is the Cartan-Leray ss: $H^p(X_{\rm Zar}, R^qf_*\mathbf{Z}(n))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X_{\rm an},\mathbf{Z}(n))$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @DanielLitt and Merlin I edited the question. Now it should be much clearer!

Comment: OK, so there is an exact sequence $$\cdots\to R^{n-1}f_*\Omega_X^{*<n}\to R^nf_*\mathbb{Z}(n)_D\to R^nf_*\mathbb{Z}(n)\to R^nf_*\Omega_X^{*<n}\cdots \to$$ (I may have screwed up the indices).  Have you tried chasing through the spectral sequence arising from this? I imagine this would give the result in your final question, or at least tell you the obstruction to answering it...

Comment: If we can edit the question and rephrase it in a much better way, maybe we should!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I did. The old question is at the end, under the subtitle "The same question, as previously formulated". The current formulation is the better one suggested by Merlin.

Comment: @DanielLitt I see what you have in mind. I'll try it now.
Anyway, my expectation is that my question has positive answer, even integrally, and the whole difficulty of the Hodge Conjecture should be about the first map in $(*)$. The second map in $(*)$ is only an edge map in a Leray ss. It has no content in terms of algebraic cycles and cycle maps. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Indeed; I’m not suggesting a way to prove the Hodge conjecture.

Comment: @schs, I know. That's why I suggest you remove the initial comment which sort of states you haven't :-)

Comment: Ah! Sorry I didn't follow you :) Thanks!